# "used by another process" error

Tags: c#

i have an object that is being accessed by 2 events simulataneously.

first, a user-defined event will access it, then the projectItemsEvent_ItemAdded event, opens it again.

and got this error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

please help!

thanks

Code Example:

```
void ProjectItemEvents_ItemAdded()
{
   Util util = new Util(_applicationObject.Solution, CurrentSelectedProject)

   if (name != null)
   {
     util.AddNewObject();
   }
}

void addItem(object sender, WebReferenceEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4500);
    Util util = new Util(_applicationObject.Solution, CurrentSelectedProject)
    util.AddNewObject();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is located in code that neither you nor we can see.  You need help from the whomever implemented the library you use.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're opening a file in both of the event handlers (hard to say for sure without code examples).

If you're just reading the file (rather than modifying/overwriting it), you could open it for shared access and allow multiple processes to have the same file open.

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"C:\someFile.txt");
FileStream fs = fi.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

If you post some code snippets, we might be able to help you integrate the change into what you already have.

**UPDATE**

After looking at your code, my guess is that there is a File Acess problem inside of the `Util` class. Can you also post its constructor?

Comment: UPDATE:

I hope this is enough:

public class Util
{
  public Util(Solution solution, Project project)
  {
     /** some code here **/
  }
}

Comment: @little_gurl - No, unfortunately that's not enough. The code there must be doing some kind of file access (directly or indirectly, which is what I'm trying to figure out).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the **lock** keyword, if there is no way for you to avoid the events from colliding.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(VS.80).aspx

http://www.toolazy.me.uk/template.php?content=lock(this)_causes_deadlocks.xml

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure to close the FileStream after you finish reading the file.

FileStream.Close();